# O atributo for de um elemento label serve pra alguma coisa?

Tags: html

Vejo vários exemplos de código em que o atributo "for" é setado em labels.

Mas na prática, setar ou não esse atributo influencia em algo na página?

Ex:

```
<label for="male">Male</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"><br>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O atributo `for` faz um tipo de *link* entre a `label` e o `input`. Logo o `for` tem que apontar para o ID do `input`.

Outra forma de uso é que vc pode fazer vários tipos de customização pelo CSS escondendo o `input` default do browser por exemplo e usando a própria `label` como se fosse o botão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui tem um exemplo bem básico do que vc pode fazer apenas com CSS e interagindo com a `label`

```css
label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
    content: url(https://unsplash.it/40/40)
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    content: url(https://placekitten.com/40/40)
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="teste">
<label class="desc animate" for="teste">Troca</label>
```

Veja o que a documentação oficial **W3C** fala sobre o uso de várias `label`s fazendo o `for` para o mesmo elemento. https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-for

> More than one `LABEL` may be associated with the same control by
>   creating multiple references via the `for` attribute.
>
> *Mais de um `LABEL` pode estar associado ao mesmo controle, criando*
>   *várias referências por meio do atributo `for`.*

Veja que vc pode ter mais de uma `label` com o mesmo valor no `for`, diferente do `ID` que só pode um. Resumindo vc pode ter vários `for` apontando para o mesmo `ID`. Isso é bem interessante pois em determinados pontos vc pode ter botões que apontam para o mesmo lugar, como exemplo um btn no topo da página e outro no final porém que apontam para o mesmo ID.

**Agora vamos a melhor parte, se vc leu até aqui vc merece!**

Usando por exemplo uma regra CSS que seja `input:checked + elemento {}` vc pode interagir com o estilos que vieram antes do `label`. **É como se vc pudesse trocar o estilo do Pai interagindo com o Filho usando um input:checked como toggle!**

**Para entender melhor veja o exemplo abaixo. A `label` vem no final, mas ela interagem como o `span` que vem acima dele!**

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
input + span {
  color: red;
}
input:checked + span {
  color: blue;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>div1
  <div>&nbspdiv2
    <div>&nbsp&nbspdiv3
      <input type="checkbox" id="fbtn" name="fbtn"> <!-- input que faz a ancora de estilo -->
      <span>Esse texto vai trocar de cor mesmo vindo antes do label que o ativa</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<b>esse conjunto de label troca a cor do texto que vem antes dele!</b><br>
<label for="fbtn"> Label -> com <i>for</i> pro checkbox</label><br>
<label for="fbtn"> Label -> com o mesmo <i>for</i> que o anterior</label>
```

Além disso a `label` faz parte da semântica dos "botões" e é imprescindível para os leitores de tela, facilita muito a acessibilidade e ajuda a marcar os botões. Aqui tem uma documentação da `W3C` sobre isso: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/

**Falando em UX e mobile** - O `for` também é muito bom para sites e sistemas `mobile`, onde o `radio` e o `checkbox` são pequenos e vc pode marca-los clicando na `label` sem precisar dar zoom, ou depender do user-agente do browser mobile.

***OBS1:*** o `for` também linka a `label` a outro elementos do `form` como `input type="text" / type="number" / type="password" etc`

***OBS2:*** o `for` também existe para o elemento `<output>` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp

Answer (score 5):

A tag `<label>` se associada a um elemento do formulário permite que você "clique" nesse elemento clicando em sua label.

Essa funcionalidade é especialmente útil se for usada em `checboxes`, `botões` e `radio buttons`. Nesse caso você vai poder acioná-los também clicando nos textos ao invés de TER de clicar nos elementos.

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label