# Atributo Checked não responde com sr-only

Tags: css3, bootstrap-4, sass

Estou escondendo o `<input type="radio">` com a classe `sr-only` do `bootstrap`, e o problema que ocorre é o seguinte:

- **Com a classe** `sr-only` **ativa:**

  1. Os `radio` não são desmarcados caso eu clique no outro
  2. O `.card` fica colorido ao clicar
- **Sem a classe** `sr-only`**:**

  1. Os `radio` são desmarcados caso eu clique no outro
  2. O `.card` não fica colorido ao clicar

**O que estou tentando fazer é simplesmente o seguinte:**

- Ao clicar no determinado `input`, será colorido com o atributo `background-color` o mesmo.

**Porque está acontecendo isto e como resolver?**

**Animação**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-6">
    <label for="step-one-form-sex-male" data-for="step-one-form-sex-male" style="width: 100% !important;">
        <input type="radio" name="step-one-form-personal-information-sex" value="Male">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
                <img src="./dist/img/doctor_male.png" alt="" style="width: 4rem">
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-center py-2">
                <h7 class="card-title font-weight-bold" style="font-size: .87rem"> SOU HOMEM</h7>
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-6">
    <label for="step-one-form-sex-female" id="tst" data-for="step-one-form-sex-female" style="width: 100% !important;">
        <input type="radio" name="step-one-form-personal-information-sex" value="Female" class="sr-only">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
                <img src="./dist/img/doctor_female.png" alt="" style="width: 4rem">
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-center py-2">
                <h7 class="card-title font-weight-bold" style="font-size: .87rem">
                    SOU MULHER
                </h7>
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

**SASS**

```
   label {
        &[data-for="step-one-form-sex-female"] {
            & {
                input {
                    &:checked + .card { 
                        @include createBorder('rounded', solid, 1px, #FF648F);

                        .card-footer {
                            @include createColor('light-rose-1', background-color);
                            @include createColor('white', color);   
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            &:hover {
                @include media-breakpoint-lg {
                    .card {
                        @include createBorder('rounded', solid, 1px, #FF648F);
                        @include createShadow(box-shadow, 'regular');

                        .card-footer {
                            @include createColor('light-rose-1', background-color);
                            @include createColor('white', color);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Em vez de colocar SASS, poderia colocar o CSS final, isso ajuda bastante a reproduzir o cenário.

Comment: Curiosidade: você está usando SASS, mas definiu várias propriedades com CSS inline; fez isso por algum motivo específico?

Comment: @Sam ia ficar muito grande o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc tem 2 `labels` diferentes, cada um com um `data-for` específico `data-for="step-one-form-sex-male"` e `data-for="step-one-form-sex-female"`

Porem no SASS vc colocou apenas a referencia para um elemento

```
label {
        &[data-for="step-one-form-sex-female"] { ....
```

Deveria ser algo como abaixo, incluindo o `sex-male` na regra

```
label {
        &[data-for="step-one-form-sex-male"],
        &[data-for="step-one-form-sex-female"] { ....
```

Outro problema é que o `for=""` da `label` tem que ser para um `ID` no `radio`, e não um data atributo qualquer. Vc precisa coloca no `for=""` da `label` o `ID` do radio que vc quer atingir, se colocar um `<label for="minha-data">` e `<input data="minha-data">` não funciona. Seu erro nada tem a ver com o `sr-only`, apenas pelo fato que sem o `sr-only` vc consegue clicar direto no *radio button*

Para compreender melhor o `for=""` recomendo que leia essa outra resposta: [O atributo for de um elemento label serve pra alguma coisa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295679/o-atributo-for-de-um-elemento-label-serve-pra-alguma-coisa/295689#295689)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```css
label[data-for="step-one-form-sex-male"] input:checked + .card,
label[data-for="step-one-form-sex-female"] input:checked + .card {
    border: 1px solid #FF648F;
background-color: rgb(253, 165, 190);
    color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="form-group col-6">
    <label for="step-one-form-sex-male" data-for="step-one-form-sex-male" style="width: 100% !important;">
        <input type="radio" name="step-one-form-personal-information-sex" id="step-one-form-sex-male" value="Male">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
                <img src="./dist/img/doctor_male.png" alt="" style="width: 4rem">
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-center py-2">
                <h7 class="card-title font-weight-bold" style="font-size: .87rem"> SOU HOMEM</h7>
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-6">
    <label for="step-one-form-sex-female" id="tst" data-for="step-one-form-sex-female" style="width: 100% !important;">
        <input type="radio" name="step-one-form-personal-information-sex" value="Female" class="sr-only" id="step-one-form-sex-female">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
                <img src="./dist/img/doctor_female.png" alt="" style="width: 4rem">
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-center py-2">
                <h7 class="card-title font-weight-bold" style="font-size: .87rem">
                    SOU MULHER
                </h7>
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Bom dia querido, muito obrigado! Eu vou postar um complemento para a sua resposta tudo bem? Espero que goste.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS sem problemas meu caro fique a vontade, como estava em SASS eu fiz só um ajuste grosseiro para poder responder de forma simples

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta do **@hugocsl**....

O problema realmente não estava na **class="sr-only"** e sim em duas questões:

- Hierarquia de seletores e elementos errada no `SASS`
- atributo for na `label` e nos `input`

Por conta disto a minha estilização não estava funcionando, então para contornar este problema eu fiz o seguinte:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-6">
    <label data-for="step-one-form-sex-male">
        <input type="radio" name="step-one-form-personal-information-sex" value="Male" class="sr-only">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <img src="./dist/img/doctor_male.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <h7 class="card-title">SOU HOMEM</h7>
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-6">
    <label data-for="step-one-form-sex-female">
        <input type="radio" name="step-one-form-personal-information-sex" value="Female" class="sr-only">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <img src="./dist/img/doctor_female.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <h7 class="card-title">SOU MULHER</h7>
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

**SASS**

```
&#card-registration-step-form-personal-information {
    .form-group {
        &:nth-child(12),
        &:nth-child(13) {
            label {
                &[data-for="step-one-form-sex-male"] {
                    input {
                        &:checked {
                            + .card {
                                @include createColor('dark-blue-1', border-color);
                                @include createColor('white', color);
                                @include createShadow(box-shadow, 'regular');

                                .card-footer {
                                    @include createColor('dark-blue-1', background-color);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        &:hover {
                            + .card { 
                                @include createColor('dark-blue-1', border-color);
                                @include createShadow(box-shadow, 'regular');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                &[data-for="step-one-form-sex-female"] {
                    input {
                        &:checked {
                            + .card  {
                                @include createColor('light-rose-1', border-color);
                                @include createColor('white', color);
                                @include createShadow(box-shadow, 'regular');

                                .card-footer {
                                    @include createColor('light-rose-1', background-color);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        &:hover {
                            + .card { 
                                @include createColor('light-rose-1', border-color);
                                @include createShadow(box-shadow, 'regular');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```