# Form dentro de form com input com problemas

Tags: html, radiobutton

Estou com um projeto e estou desenvolvendo um questionário. Cada pergunta tem cinco alternativas e estas questões estão na mesma página, dentro de `divs`, e dentro do mesmo `form`. Segue o código:

```html
<form method="post" name="form" action="#" class=""> <!-- Form -->
  <div class="pb-3 mt-2"> <!-- Questão 1 -->
    <h4 class="titulo border-bottom">Questão 1</h4>
    <p align="justify" class="my-2 mx-3">Pergunta</p>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio mx-3 border-bottom mb-1"> <!-- Primeiro imput do tipo radio -->
      <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-   control-input">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Sim</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio mx-3 border-bottom mb-1"> <!-- Segundo imput do tipo radio -->
      <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">Não</label>
    </div>

    <div class="pb-3 mt-4"> <!-- Questão 2 -->
      <h4 class="titulo border-bottom">Questão 2</h4>
      <p align="justify" class="my-2 mx-3">Pergunta</p>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio mx-3 border-bottom mb-1"> <!-- Primeiro imput do tipo radio -->
        <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Sim</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio mx-3 border-bottom mb-1"> <!-- Segundo imput do tipo radio -->
        <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">Não</label>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" class="btn botao" style="float: right;">
</form> <!-- Fim do form -->
```

Desse jeito que estão dispostos, quando o primeiro `input` da segunda questão é marcado, o primeiro `input` da primeira questão que é marcado. E assim com o segundo também. Sempre é a primeira questão que está sendo marcada. Eu descobri que é por causa dos `IDs` dos elementos e tentei mudar para `CLASS` e continuou com o problema.

Como poderia resolver isso? Colocaria cada questão como um form?

Quero enviar tudo junto no final. Estou utilizando o estilo de `Forms` do Bootstrap.

Desde já, muito obrigado.

Comment: O problema está no `name` dos seus elementos. Todas as opções possuem o mesmo nome.

Comment: `id` é um IDentificador e deve ser único. Inputs com `name` iguais se sobrescrevem. Seria interessante você começar estudando o básico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o problema seja no valor do atributo `for` da `label` e no `name` do grupo de `btns`. Repare que o `for` é usado para lincar o texto da `label` ao `radio-button`, assim caso o usuário clique no texto o radio é marcado.

E o `name` é o que faz os botões serem do mesmo grupo. Por exemplo se vc quer que os `btns` da questão um sejam só relacionados entre si use o mesmo `name` nos `radios` dessa questão. Se vc quer que os `radios` da questão 1 e 2 sejam relacionados entre si formando um grupo só use o mesmo `name` em todos os `radios`

Para entender mais sobre o atributo `for` leia aqui: [O atributo for de um elemento label serve pra alguma coisa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295679/o-atributo-for-de-um-elemento-label-serve-pra-alguma-coisa/295689#295689)

```html
<form method="post" name="form" action="#" class="">
    <!-- Form -->
    <div class="pb-3 mt-2">
        <!-- Questão 1 -->
        <h4 class="titulo border-bottom">Questão 1</h4>
        <p align="justify" class="my-2 mx-3">Pergunta</p>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mx-3 border-bottom mb-1">
            <!-- Primeiro imput do tipo radio -->
            <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-   control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Sim</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mx-3 border-bottom mb-1">
            <!-- Segundo imput do tipo radio -->
            <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">Não</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pb-3 mt-4">
        <!-- Questão 2 -->
        <h4 class="titulo border-bottom">Questão 2</h4>
        <p align="justify" class="my-2 mx-3">Pergunta</p>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mx-3 border-bottom mb-1">
            <!-- Primeiro imput do tipo radio -->
            <input type="radio" id="customRadio11" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio11">Sim</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mx-3 border-bottom mb-1">
            <!-- Segundo imput do tipo radio -->
            <input type="radio" id="customRadio22" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio22">Não</label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" class="btn botao" style="float: right;">
    </div>

</form> <!-- Fim do form -->
```

---

**Separando os grupos**

Caso queira que os `radios` da questão 2 sejam independente dos `radios` da questão 1. Use o mesmo `name` nos `radios` da 1 e um nome diferente nos `radios` da questão 2

```html
<form method="post" name="form" action="#" class="">
    <!-- Form -->
    <div class="pb-3 mt-2">
        <!-- Questão 1 -->
        <h4 class="titulo border-bottom">Questão 1</h4>
        <p align="justify" class="my-2 mx-3">Pergunta</p>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mx-3 border-bottom mb-1">
            <!-- Primeiro imput do tipo radio -->
            <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-   control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Sim</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mx-3 border-bottom mb-1">
            <!-- Segundo imput do tipo radio -->
            <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">Não</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pb-3 mt-4">
        <!-- Questão 2 -->
        <h4 class="titulo border-bottom">Questão 2</h4>
        <p align="justify" class="my-2 mx-3">Pergunta</p>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mx-3 border-bottom mb-1">
            <!-- Primeiro imput do tipo radio -->
            <input type="radio" id="customRadio11" name="customRadio2" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio11">Sim</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio mx-3 border-bottom mb-1">
            <!-- Segundo imput do tipo radio -->
            <input type="radio" id="customRadio22" name="customRadio2" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio22">Não</label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" class="btn botao" style="float: right;">
    </div>

</form> <!-- Fim do form -->
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Ajudou muito.

Comment: @pedromanoel  legal que deu certo ai! Se vc acha que resolveu o problema considere marcar a resposta como aceita nesse ícone `✔` abaixo das setinhas da resposta, assim ela não fica pendente no site como pergunta sem resposta aceita mesmo já tendo sido resolvida. []´s